# Azure web.config rewrite rule, not working

Tags: php, azure, iis, url-rewriting

Im brand new with azure web apps and iis url rewrite. I have been searching for a solution for a couple of hours now with no luck

the idea is to have this rewrite rules (in php linux server are like follow:)

```
RewriteRule ^telefono-de-([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\.\-]+) /informacion/index.php?keyword=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^v2/telefono-de-([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\.\-]+) /v2/index.php?keyword=$1 [NC]
```

But im not being able to replicate same thing in azure.

This is what i got so far with no success:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
</staticContent>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With,Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT,PATCH" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="algo" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^telefono-de-([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\.\-]+)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/informacion/index.php?keyword={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And it throws an error:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

Please expert dude of azure, wherever you are, give me a hint what am i doing wrong!